# Selecting all elements that meet a criteria using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using selenium, is there a way to have the script pick out elements that meet a certain criteria?

What I'm exactly trying to do is have selenium select all Twitch channels that have more than X viewers. If you inspect element, you find this:

```
<p class="info"
    562
    viewers on
    <a class="js-profile-link" href="/hey_jase/profile" 
    data-tt_content="live_channel" data-tt_content_index="1"
    data-tt_medium="twitch_directory" data-ember-action="1471">
    Hey_Jase
    </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can find all twitch channel links. Then, filter them based on the view count.

Something along these lines:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver


THRESHOLD = 100  

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s+viewers on")
for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p.info a[data-tt_content=live_channel]"):
    text = link.find_element_by_xpath("..").text  # get to the p parent element
    match = pattern.search(text)  # extract viewers count
    if match:
        viewers_count = int(match.group(1))
        if viewers_count >= THRESHOLD:
            print(link.text, viewers_count)
```

Comment: What are you importing and where does the parameter for pattern come from?

Comment: @Astrum I've added a little bit more to the snippet hoping to make it a little bit clearer. The pattern is to extract the number of viewers from the p element's text.

Comment: I really am lost. I guess I'll just list my questions.

1. what is re.compile, and where does that parameter come from. 
2. Where did you get that css path? When I use firebug to find the path to the viewer element, I get a very long string. 
3. What is text = ...? doing? I thought the css_selector method was finding our elements.

Comment: I actually edited the line to "p.info" and left the rest the same and it worked. My question then is what is the "match =...xpath("..")" doing? And I assume that match.group() just takes all returned elements and groups them into an array?

Comment: @Astrum okay, the `..` part is getting us to the parent element of the current. The `match.group()` extracts the capturing group from the match.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give an exact code as we only get a small sample of the HTML, but this should work if you tweak it a bit.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.website.com')

source = driver.page_source
location = source.find('<p class="info"')
source = source[location+16:] #adjust the +16 to maybe +15 or w/e depending on the exact source page you get
location_second = source.find('viewers on') #assuming there is a space between the actual number of viewers and the
source = int(source[:location_second-1])  #adjust the -1 to maybe -2 or w/e depending on the exact source page you get
if source > x: # replace x with whatever number is your minimum viewers
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-profile-link') #might need to use x-path if you have multiple instances of the same class name
```

Comment: What exactly does source[location+16] do? .

Comment: source = source[location+16:]  -> location is the index position of the text "<p class="info"" and +16 because you have 15 letters in "<p class="info"" + 1 space. This will give us the exact index position of where the actual number of viewers is.